# Create a list showing the matching strings of given input java

Tags: java, string

In a java program I want to show a list of strings already initiated as output which are matching to the given input .
AND also It should show 100 % matching as first and 99 % next and so on.

Comment: Looking for the Strings similarity index? See [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

Comment: Hi Arun, please post your code attempt and highlight what exactly isn’t working. Also see: [mcve].

Comment: I have used string.matches but cant make it as an order of more matching string first